# Failed to launch instance: Timeout while waiting on RPC response - topic: "network"

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am trying to setup devstack on Ubuntu12.04.4.64Bit VM.

## localrc :

```
ENABLED_SERVICES=g-api,g-reg,key,n-api,n-crt,n-cpu,n-net,n-cond,n-sch,rabbit,mysql,horizon
DATABASE_PASSWORD=passwd
RABBIT_PASSWORD=passwd
SERVICE_TOKEN=passwd
SERVICE_PASSWORD=passwd
ADMIN_PASSWORD=passwd

MYSQL_PASSWORD=passwd
HOST_IP=localhost
SERVICE_HOST=$HOST_IP
IMAGE_HOST=$HOST_IP
IDENTITY_HOST=$HOST_IP

LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log
LOG_COLOR=True
VERBOSE=True
SCREEN_LOGDIR=/opt/stack/logs


VIRT_DRIVER=vsphere
VMWAREAPI_IP=192.168.100.192
VMWAREAPI_USER=root
VMWAREAPI_PASSWORD=vmware
VMWAREAPI_CLUSTER=DRS
VMWAREAPI_COMPUTE_DRIVER=vmwareapi.VMwareVCDriver
VMWAREAPI_WSDL_LOC=http://127.0.0.1:8080/vmware/SDK/wsdl/vim25/vimService.wsdl


FLAT_INTERFACE=eth1
```

===============

Installation works fine. All the services are installed and running fine. But when I tried to launch the instance using horizon, it failed with the below error,

"
Error: Failed to launch instance "v1": Please try again later [Error: Timeout while waiting on RPC response - topic: "network", RPC method: "get_instance_nw_info" info: ""].
"

I am not sure whats going wrong. I googled error but didn't get much help from search. Can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

that is too general. I can only tell you have a messed up network. look into nova-api log and give me more leads.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have configured private network for configuring devstack. So my devstack VM has two nics. One is connected to private network(eth1) and other has external network access(eth0). And I am using nova networking(no neutron). Apart from this, I didn't do much before installation. Let me check in the api logs if I get anything there.

Comment: I am seeing an assert on n-net screen (logged into screen -x). Command: sudo nova-rootwrap /etc/nova/rootwrap.conf iptables-restore -c
Exit code: 2
Stdout: ''
Stderr: 'iptables-restore v1.4.12: Bad IP address "localhost"\n\n .......

Comment: Ok now do two things. First show me your nova.conf, rootwrap.conf and api-paste.ini. Next post the logs from /var/log/nova-api.log . Don't paste the entire. Just the logs that come when you try to run an instance. Remove any sensitive information from your conf files while pasting.

Comment: Thanks a lot Akilesh for the help. I made some changes to the underlying network configuration to my devstack vm and added devstack IP in localrc file (instead of localhost). Now its working fine. I am still trying setup another devstack VM to make it work with my original networking setting, I will post my conf files if I am not able to configure it.